# Avoid dropping the variable when wrapped into a struct

Tags: rust, rodio

I have a Rodio's [Sink](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/struct.Sink.html) wrapper in `HAudioSink`. I also implement a `try_new_from_haudio` function that, in short, creates a `Sink` instance, wrap it in `HAudioSink` and already starts playing the first audio.
In `Sink`'s docs it states: "Dropping the Sink stops all sounds. You can use detach if you want the sounds to continue playing". So when `try_new_from_haudio`is returning, it drops the original sink and the sound is stopping when it shouldn't.

So my question here is: what should I do to avoid it dropping when I create an instance of `HAudioSink`? Is `ManuallyDrop` the way to go?

```
struct HAudioSink {
    sink: Sink,
}

impl HAudioSink {
    pub fn try_new_from_haudio<T>(haudio: HAudio<T>) -> HResult<Self>
    where
        T: NativeType + Float + ToPrimitive,
    {
        let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default()?;
        let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();
        let nchannels = haudio.nchannels();
        let nframes = haudio.nframes();
        let sr = haudio.sr();
        let mut data_interleaved: Vec<f32> = Vec::with_capacity(nchannels * nframes);
        let values = haudio
            .inner()
            .inner()
            .values()
            .as_any()
            .downcast_ref::<PrimitiveArray<T>>()
            .unwrap();

        for f in 0..nframes {
            for ch in 0..nchannels {
                data_interleaved.push(values.value(f + ch * nframes).to_f32().unwrap());
            }
        }

        let source = SamplesBuffer::new(u16::try_from(nchannels).unwrap(), sr, data_interleaved);

        sink.append(source);

        Ok(HAudioSink { sink })
    }

    // Sleeps the current thread until the sound ends.
    pub fn sleep_until_end(&self) {
        self.sink.sleep_until_end();
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    //this test doesn't work
    #[test]
    fn play_test() {
        let sink = HAudioSink::try_new_from_file("../testfiles/gs-16b-2c-44100hz.wav").unwrap();

        sink.append_from_file("../testfiles/gs-16b-2c-44100hz.wav")
            .unwrap();

        sink.sleep_until_end();
    }
}
```

If I put `sink.sleep_until_end()` inside `try_new_from_haudio`, just before returning `Ok`, it works.

check the following link for the reproducible example of this issue: https://github.com/RustAudio/rodio/issues/476

Comment: If you want to keep using the `Sink` just keep it around, if not use `detach` `ManuallyDrop` is a very niche struct rarely needed by high level code.

Comment: But how would I do that? Sink appears to drop, and so music stops, when `try_new_from_audio` closes its scope

Comment: Store the result in a variable, `let sink = HAudioSink::try_new_from_audio(…)`.

Comment: Ok I edited my original post so you can understand it better.. I was already doing this step you meantioned. The test only works when I call sleep inside `try_new_from_audio`. When I call sleep inside the test, it doesn't work. I suspect it's the original sink being dropped that does this effect.

Comment: @cafce25 I created an issue with a reproducible example in Rodio. https://github.com/RustAudio/rodio/issues/476

Comment: You should add the [mre] you produced for the issue here, too, next time start with that, would have saved both of us some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for the `_stream` too "If this is dropped playback will end & attached OutputStreamHandles will no longer work."
see the docs on [`OutputStream`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.16.0/rodio/struct.OutputStream.html). So you have to store it alongside your `Sink`:

```rust
pub struct SinkWrapper {
    pub sink: Sink,
    pub stream: OutputStream,
}

impl SinkWrapper {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
        let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();

        // Add a dummy source of the sake of the example.
        let source = SineWave::new(440.0)
            .take_duration(Duration::from_secs_f32(1.))
            .amplify(2.);
        sink.append(source);

        Self { sink, stream }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks! I will add the reproducible example as a link in the original post.